# How do you run tensorflow on colaboratory?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use Google's Colaboratory. The first line of output was hopeful.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

But then I got this error message.

```
    ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

That error apparently triggered another error. (Sorry for the long stack trace, but the error message itself suggested including it when asking for help.)

```
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0b846698ae4a> in <module>()
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import matplotlib.pylab as plt
----> 4 from keras.models import Sequential
      5 from keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer
      6 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 
      8 # Globally-importable utils.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py in <module>()
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py in <module>()
     82 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     83     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 84     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     85 else:
     86     raise ValueError('Unknown backend: ' + str(_BACKEND))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in <module>()
      3 from __future__ import print_function
      4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages
      7 from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
     26 from tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Below that was a suggestion to consult `https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems`.

But that page is about installing TensorFlow from source. I'm not trying to install from source. I just want a runnable version that I can call.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Google Colab comes with all the basic packages of TensorFlow, Keras, Numpy, Pandas, and Matplotlib installed. I've tested it by spinning a new notebook on Colab and all seems to be working.
Kindly post all your preliminary import statements, perhaps sometime is not right there. Cheers.

Comment: I tried a new Notebook again also, and it worked this time. The previous time I tried to import TensorFlow-gpu. I think that got me into trouble. Do you know whether the default Colab version uses the GPU version of TensorFlow? When running my code on Colab it ran more slowly than on my personal machine, which doesn't have a TensorFlow-compatible GPU.

Comment: Please modify your question or ask this as a new question, so I can provide the answer for you. This is important to maintain the direct question and answer format of StackOverflow. Thanks.